# memory order with multiple stores

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, lock-free

Consider the example below. Assume that `barrier` is initialized to 0.

There is one producer thread and two consumer threads that constantly check `barrier`. If the barrier is set, they decrease `runcnt`. The producer thread waits for `runcnt` to reach 0. I am confused about the order of multiple store operations inside the producer.

If the order is like it is written, I think the code would run as expected. But if the `barrier` store is reordered before `runcnt` store, it seems the assert check would fail.
Am I missing anything? Is there a way to fix this?

```cpp
extern atomic<int> barrier[2];
atomic_int runcnt{0};

void producer() {
    runcnt.store(2, memory_order_relaxed);
    barrier[0].store(1, memory_order_relaxed);
    barrier[1].store(1, memory_order_relaxed);
    
    while (runcnt.load(memory_order_relaxed)) {
        cpu_pause();
    }
}

void consumer(unsigned index) {
   while (true) {
    if (barrier[index].exchange(false, memory_order_relaxed)) {
      int prev = runcnt.fetch_sub(1, memory_order_relaxed);
      assert(prev > 0);
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: A release fence does prevent LoadStore reordering.  The two it doesn't block are LoadLoad and StoreLoad.  https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ / https://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/ .  But yes, the useful property here is blocking StoreStore reordering.  (In order to implement the C++ semantics of everything before the fence happening-before any store after the fence.)  If release fences and operations allowed LoadStore reordering, reading a variable while you hold a lock could get a value after the next thread's critical section had already written

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If the order is like it is written* - You mean if the operations happen to become visible in an order that would also be allowed by `seq_cst`?  You could of course require that with `seq_cst` on all the operations.

I think the minimum in the reader side is for `barrier[i].exchange` to be `acquire`.

And in the writer side, both `barrier[i]` stores need to be `release`, or to put one `std::atomic_thread_fence(release)` right after `runcnt.store`, so it's between that and either barrier store.

That makes the `exchange` synchronize with whichever `barrier` store it loads, assuming that it loaded a `1` so the `if` body runs at all.

`runcnt.store(relaxed)` ; `barrier[0].store(release)` ; `barrier[1].store(relaxed)` would *not* be sufficient in the C++ memory model or even when compiling for some ISAs: the final relaxed store can pass the release store because it's only a 1-way barrier.   This is a key difference between fences and operations: https://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/ .  Even making the middle store `seq_cst` wouldn't be sufficient, it's still just an operation, not 2-way fence.

Comment: Thank you @peter-cordes. I would like to focus on the solution with `std::atomic_thread_fence(release)`  What confuses me is that we can fix the code by only changing the producer side without adding additional acquire barriers in the consumer.

Comment: @Roman: A release fence in the producer still requires the reader to use an `exchage(acquire)`, same as with release stores.  Sorry if that wasn't clear from the answer; I was just considering an alternate way to get sufficient ordering in the writer that would be cheaper on ISAs like ARMv7 where each release store would include a barrier at least as strong as `fence(release)`, actually `fence(seq_cst)` unfortunately.  (ARMv8 fixes that.).  Maybe the reader minimum ordering should be a separate paragraph.

Comment: But why do we need acquire in case there are no other variables like in this example? Can fetch_sub be reordered before the barrier read?

Comment: @Roman: Yes, relaxed RMWs on different objects are separately atomic but not ordered wrt. anything including each other.  Without a happens-before, there's no guarantee in the ISO C++ memory model.  I wouldn't be surprised if no ISAs can break it in practice, since it's an RMW that includes a store before a branch, and IDK if any ISAs can actually have two relaxed atomic RMWs in flight at once on separate locations, like having the load side of the `fetch_sub` start speculatively thanks to branch prediction.

Comment: So for sake of keeping my sanity, I should replace RMW with loads when thinking of memory order semantics, got ya!

Answer (score 1):

As @peter-cordes pointed out, unlike regular release stores that are uni-directional, `std::atomic_thread_fence(release)` serves as bidirectional barrier between stores ([later loads can still be reordered across it](https://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/)).

Therefore, this is the fixed code, also using an `acquire` load in the consumer:

```cpp
void producer() {
    runcnt.store(2, memory_order_relaxed);

    std::atomic_thread_fence(release);  // <- Prevents reordering of barrier stores before runcnt.store. 

    barrier[0].store(1, memory_order_relaxed);
    barrier[1].store(1, memory_order_relaxed);
    
    while (runcnt.load(memory_order_relaxed)) {
        cpu_pause();
    }
}


void consumer(unsigned index) {
   while (true) {
    // we "ignore" the branching and RMW when we plan
    // memory order semantics. 
    // `acquire` prevents fetch_sub being reordered before the `exchange`.  
    if (barrier[index].exchange(false, memory_order_acquire)) {
      int prev = runcnt.fetch_sub(1, memory_order_relaxed);
      assert(prev > 0);
    }
   }
}
```